# ASP.Net SSL cetification Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ssl, iis

Situation :
I have 2 websites(let's say Website-1 and Website-2).
Website-1 has a menu which redirects to Website-2.

When receiving requist from Website-1, 
Website-2 confirms that request has actually arrived from Website-1 using UrlReferrer information.

Problem :
I would like to install self-signed certificate for Website-2
but when I do so almost every browser displays a page for invalid SSL certificate (which I bypass by clicking "Proceed to ___" from advance option)and thus UrlReferrer information is lost.

Question :
This setting works fine with [no certificate] or [third-party certificate(recognized valid by browser)] but
Is there any way to get UrlReferrer information with self-signed certificate?

I would be grateful if anyone could help me.

Comment: Let the browser trust the self signed certificate. That's browser dependent configuration.

Comment: *Website-2 confirms that request has actually arrived from Website-1 using UrlReferrer information.*  this is a very weak verification...  It will break in many ways.

Comment: @LexLi I can't have each and every client import self signed certificate into their browsers. For me this is just not realistic.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Okay, then what do you suggest?

Comment: I do not know, you do not give enough details. Maybe you just need some kind of authentication or authorization. Like some SSO? I do not know what website1 and website2 do and their relation, but the referer issue is orthogonal to your SSL issue. Note that clients may not sent referer at all, it is under their complete control.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Okay, let me explain it in more details. Website-1 has list of of features. Consider each feature a different website. If I want to access any feature I have to login through Website-1 and then select Website-2,3,4,etc. In this scenario Website-1 is used just for login and loading appropriate features according user authorization.

Comment: "I can't have each and every client import self signed certificate into their browsers. For me this is just not realistic." Then you ask an invalid question. If your goal is to have each and every client trust your certificate, then obviously it cannot be a self-signed one. Why do you want to chase the impossible yourself?

Comment: @LexLi Thank you for the help. I implemented a SSO model and represented the client with a proposal to get an authorized SSL certificate.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thank you for the help. I implemented a SSO model and represented the client with a proposal to get an authorized SSL certificate.